# How to record error in R without using sink()?

Tags: r

`sink(type='message')` is good, but return value `NULL` is bad to me.
Then, I am asking how to record error into a file without using `sink`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm fully understanding your question, but if you want to catch an error and then control what the event is should an error occur, you want to look at `?tryCatch`.
That said, here's an example of how you can catch a raised error within a function and return it as a string.

### EDIT to show how to write to a file if you prefer

```
f <- function(...){
    tryCatch(is.character(...), error = function(e){
        var_e <- capture.output(e, file = "errors", append = TRUE)
        readLines("errors") ## just to push the output to our variable at the terminal
    })
}
```

#### Forcing an error by passing a non-quoted string into the function will capture the warning as a character object to variable `a`

```
> a <- f(noquotes)
> a
[1] "<simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): object 'noquotes' not found>"
> typeof(a)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: It's a good alternative to `sink`, but my scripts will be considered as condition object, I could not get the script output result.

Comment: you'll need to provide more info on what you mean... such as the script itself or an example that is close to it and why you need to capture the error